# How to run `npm react-native run-ios` after upgrading mac os and upgrading xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I picked up a react-native project from 2018.  I was able to get the app to work in a simulator by typing `npm install; npx react-native run-ios` on a 2012 mac mini that had Xcode 9.0 installed.

However, the iPhone 11 was not available from the list of simulators.  I read that I needed Xcode 11+ to get iPhone 11 simulator.  So i upgraded my mac mini from OS 10.13 to OS 10.15, then I upgrade Xcode to version 12.0.

I loaded up the new Xcode and entered my Apple ID.  I then went to terminal and typed `npx react-native run-ios`, but I got the error:

```
`instruments` is now deprecated in favor of 'xcrun xctrace' (see `man xctrace` for more information on its replacement)

Could not find iPhone 6 simulator
```

So then I ran the command `rm -rf node_modules; npm install;`, but then I got the error:

```
npm ERR! error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

And trying to run `npx react-native run-ios` gives the error:

```
Command `run-ios` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
```

How do you make `npx react-native run-ios` to work?

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

i think your project choose IP6 is default simulator, to change it,
Clone your project,  in package.json change

> "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X""

then run : yarn ios

if not, open your project "yourproject.xcworkspace" with Xcode, and run it.
[image]

if the error persists, show your package.json for everyone to consider